# Android ActionBarSherlock Top Bar

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

[image]

I want to have an Action Bar like foursquare. What I want is tabs such as **Friends, Explore and Me**. Also, above the tabs I want to have a custom layout that includes some buttons such as **foursquare logo, Refresh and Check-In** in foursquare. I created tabs but I could not change the layout above tabs in ActionBarSherlock. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you provide us with a printscreen of Foursquare's app?

Comment: I added the ps of foursquare.

Comment: I am pretty sure that they use an personal implementation of the bar, and they are not using ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu You must be right but do you know how can I add a custom layout above tabs using ActionBarSherlock?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve a Foursquare look you do not need to be thinking of creating a layout above the tabs. When using Actionbar Sherlock you only need to worry about:

1. Making a background for the top bar
2. Making a logo for the top bar
3. Adding items in a menu.xml file that ActionbarSherlock will use to populate the top section with Buttons (as long as a style using Actionbar Sherlock style is attached to thw activity).

So, for 1. and 2. it's all about using styles.xml file (should reside in the values folder in the res folder) like so:

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="absForceOverflow">true</item>       
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item> <-- the background for top bar
    <item name="icon">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item> <-- the logo that goes top left in the top bar
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/bg_striped_split</item> <-- the image used between the menu items
</style>
```

For 3. all you need to do is create menu items under menu.xml (should reside in the menu folder (if not there, create one in the res folder)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     

<item android:id="@+id/menu_prefs"
      android:icon="@drawable/settings_icon"
      android:title="Preferences"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" /> 
</menu>
```

The last thing you have to do to see the menu items is use these functions in the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {

    Intent intent;

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {   
    case R.id.menu_prefs:

        // Launch Preference Activity
        intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Preferences.class);           
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: There is another issue, due to your code I want to have a ListNavigation or ActionMode when menu_prefs clicked. Also, there is a tab. How can I manage this?

Comment: @Richard Lewin - When using the example above, the "blue" top navigation appears below my tabs -- any idea why, and how to get it above?  Also when landscaped the top bar collapses into the tabs - anyway to force it to stay at top?

Comment: The top bar collapsing is default action bar behaviour and therefore should not (and to my knowledge can't be) altered. The issue of the bar appearing below the tabs is unusual as the tabs should be below the navigation bar and should collapse into the navigation bar. A screen shot of what's happening would be of great help. Can you send me it via Stack Overflow?

Comment: @RichardLewin No problem, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356422/tabs-with-actionbarsherlock-and-fragments-with-top-nav-bar thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To set your custom action items (refresh, check in, ...) you must override onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) and set your custom menu.

e.g:

File menu/my_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
        android:title="refresh"
        android:showAsAction="always">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Then in your activity (or fragment):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
  MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);

  // Allow activity and fragments to add items
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

  return true;
}
```

And to be notified when they are selected, just override onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
  switch (item.getItemId())
  {
    case android.R.id.refresh :
      // refresh your data...
      return true;

    default :
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Chinaski - Same as above: When using the example above, the "blue" top navigation appears below my tabs -- any idea why, and how to get it above? Also when landscaped the top bar collapses into the tabs - anyway to force it to stay at top?