# Custom SherlockActionBar layout above Tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm newbie to SherlockActionBar development and what I want is the "Foursquare-like" top action bar with tabs under it, see:

[image]

As Richard Lewin described in [Android ActionBarSherlock Top Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412841/android-actionbarsherlock-top-bar) I can easily add menu actions like "Search" or "Checkin" that will appear to the right side of top bar, but what I should do if I need to add custom "Up" button (instead of logo) and custom (bold, for example) title? Can I do it using only SherlockActionBar XML-styles or I need to implement new components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexander, you need to create custom layout for your action bar, see example here
[Show dropdown programatically in ActionBar / ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737500/show-dropdown-programatically-in-actionbar-actionbarsherlock/11794124#11794124)

In this example described actionbar with spinner and two actions.

Answer (score 1):

In your activity, enable the up button (typically in onCreate() ) :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

then implement its behavior :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:

        // do something

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

For actionbar theming : http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html

And for the tabs I think you can do it like in the android 4 implementation : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Have a lot of fun :)

Comment: do you need more info / help ?