# Tabs with ActionBarSherlock and Fragments with Top Nav bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am implementing the same design as described here: [Android ActionBarSherlock Top Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412841/android-actionbarsherlock-top-bar) and using the accepted answers code.  Although it is pushing my nav bar below my tabs:

[Valid XHTML http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/8908/tabsa.png](http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/8908/tabsa.png).

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug with ActionBarSherlock (from https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/327 ).

Cause:

> When you call setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) in onCreate() and are
>   using a tab navigation mode, the tabs will appear above the action bar
>   as opposed to below it.

Workaround:
Remove the setDisplayShowHomeEnabled call, and add this instead:

```
View homeIcon = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```